# Session not set on request laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass the variable from one function to another function inside the same controller using session I am getting the error "session not set on request"

Below is what I tried:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $sReference = $response->output_TransactionID;

    request()->session()->put('sReference', $sReference); 
}

public function sendPaymentDetails()
{
    $sReference = session('sReference');
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `StartSession` middleware set in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file? If the answer is _yes_, in which part do you have it set?

Comment: how are you calling 2 controller methods for 1 route action? ... they don't call each other so its not possible for them both to be called in a single "action" .... so when are these 2 methods being called?